# Inability to delete table cells after a certain point

Tags: ios, iphone

I have built an app which has the ability to delete cells from a table, but only if there are more than two cells.

If there are two or less cells, it only lets me select them. Any ideas?

Here's a video to visualize it: http://slavingia.com/etc/helpme.mov

Comment: Post (the relevant section of) your code. We don't know if you're talking about an HTML table, a database table, a kitchen table, or King Arthur's Round Table. And while making a movie shows some effort, I don't have the bandwidth at my hotel, and those who do are going to wonder if the .mov contains a Trojan.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize. Anyways, it's a UITableView in which as long as there are less than three UITableViewCells, they are selectable but not deletable.

Comment: You don't delete any cells in your video. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: I want to be able to delete all the table cells, but it stops at 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the datasource, in the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can see how many items are in the source, if its less than 2 then you can return none  in this method which wont allow editing, otherwise you can return delete style so you can

Comment: I want to be able to delete all the table cells, but it stops at 2.